# django-filebrowser does not generates thumnails (versions)

Tags: python, django, django-filebrowser

I`ve got a problem with django-filebrowser. It doesnt generate any thumbnails which I defined in my settings file. It stored only full image. Media folder chmoded by 755 rights.

my settings file configuration:

```
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = 'uploads/'

FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_ROOT = config.media_root

FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

FILEBROWSER_EXTENSIONS = {
'Folder': [''],
'Image': ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png', '.tif', '.tiff'],
'Document': ['.pdf', '.doc', '.rtf', '.txt', '.xls', '.csv', '.docx'],
'Video': ['.mov', '.wmv', '.mpeg', '.mpg', '.avi', '.rm'],
'Audio': ['.mp3', '.mp4', '.wav', '.aiff', '.midi', '.m4p']
}

FILEBROWSER_VERSIONS_BASEDIR = '_versions'

FILEBROWSER_VERSIONS = {
'admin_thumbnail': {'verbose_name': 'Admin Thumbnail', 'width': 60, 'height': 60, 'opts': 'crop'},
'thumbnail': {'verbose_name': 'Thumbnail (1 col)', 'width': 60, 'height': 60, 'opts': 'crop'},
'small': {'verbose_name': 'Small (2 col)', 'width': 140, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
'medium': {'verbose_name': 'Medium (4col )', 'width': 300, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
'big': {'verbose_name': 'Big (6 col)', 'width': 460, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
'large': {'verbose_name': 'Large (8 col)', 'width': 680, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
'master_thumb': {'verbose_name': u'Работы (предпросмотр)', 'width': 350, 'height': 350, 'opts': ''},
'master_large': {'verbose_name': u'Работы (увеличенная)', 'width': 800, 'height': 800, 'opts': ''},
'master_face': {'verbose_name': u'Фотография мастера', 'width': 160, 'height': 160, 'opts': ''},
'master_face_large': {'verbose_name': u'Фотография мастера', 'width': 200, 'height': 200, 'opts': ''},
'work_thumb': {'verbose_name': u'Работы (предпросмотр)', 'width': 350, 'height': 350, 'opts': ''},
'work_large': {'verbose_name': u'Работы (увеличенная)', 'width': 800, 'height': 800, 'opts': ''},
'reply_avatar': {'verbose_name': u'Аватарка для отзыва', 'width': 160, 'height': 160, 'opts': ''},
'news_preview': {'verbose_name': u'Превью для новости', 'width': 200, 'height': 200, 'opts': ''},
}

FILEBROWSER_ADMIN_VERSIONS = ['thumbnail', 'small', 'medium', 'big', 'large', 'master_thumb', 'master_large','master_face']

FILEBROWSER_ADMIN_THUMBNAIL = 'admin_thumbnail'
```

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by installing a missing libjpeg-dev.

Comment: I have the same problem with Django-filebrowser 3.6.1 over Django1.8, but in my case libjpeg8 and libjpeg8-dev are installed. I do not discard a missing library in my case, but I am clueless about how to find out...